# Not able change the hostname with cloud-init script

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, cloud-init

I have the following simple script which changes the hostname of Linux VM.

```
    #cloud-config
     hostname: my-host
```

But when launched Amazon Linux AMI with the above script in user-data hostname didn't changed. Can anyone help me about this

Comment: check the cloud-init logs?

Comment: I am not seeing any errors in cloud-init-output.log file

Comment: @hjpotter92 Issue Fixed.I have used fqdn instead of hostname. Thanks for your reply.